# Почему интерпретатор питона не проверяет type hints?

Tags: python, python-3.x, language-lawyer, дизайн-языка, типизация

Здравствуйте! В питоне есть type hint`ы, однако код вроде такого:

```
def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

add('hello', 'world')
```

отлично выполняется. Я знаю, что для проверки типов есть внешние утилиты, но не понимаю: почему синтаксис в язык добавили, а проверки из коробки нет?

Ведь внешние утилиты могут проверять без какого либо дополнительного синтаксиса, почему так активно такая идея начала обсуждаться только сейчас.

Что-то такое, кажется, не сложнее парсить:

```
#: int, int -> int
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

#: [int]
li = [1,2,3]
```

В том же js есть "strict mode", который можно включать и выключать по собственному желанию, мне кажется, что это намного логичнее. Понятно, что задачи у них разные, но ситуации, кажется, похожи.

Comment: Может быть, потому, что в проверке type hints заинтересованы в основном разработчики IDE. Ну, не разработчики даже, наверное, а продавцы.

Answer (score 6):

Type hint'ы введены [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). Держите под рукой.

> почему синтаксис в язык добавили, а проверки из коробки нет?

Вообще на любые вопросы "почему в языке Х нет фичи Y", при отсутствии явного отказа от неё, ответ "не сделали ещё, может быть когда-нибудь".

Но в PEP 484 есть [предложение](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#non-goals), очень похожее на отказ делать это частью языка:

> It should also be emphasized that **Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention.**

> Важно также отметить, что **Python останется динамически типизированным языком, и его авторы не намереваются когда-либо делать type hint'ы обязательными, даже если лишь по соглашению.**

Хотя это напрямую не исключает возможности появления *необязательных* проверок в стандартной библиотеке, это стало бы существенным шагом в сторону "статической типизации по соглашению", чего авторы языка не хотят.

Как бы там ни было, type hint'ы должны стабилизироваться в языке, прежде чем основывать на них такую крупную фичу, как встроеннные проверки. А это случится [не раньше Python 3.8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#non-typing-usage-of-annotations).

---

> Ведь внешние утилиты могут проверять без какого либо дополнительного синтаксиса

Да, но:

- Каждый анализатор вынужден для этого вводить собственный синтаксис. Возможно, когда-нибудь разные реализации пришли бы к общему де-факто стандарту. А можно сделать "превентивный стандарт", чтобы исключить другие развития событий на корню.
- Этот синтаксис должен затруднять написание аннотаций, несовместимых с описываемым кодом.

  - Комментарии очень легко сделать несовместимыми с кодом, чтобы это не случилось, нужны дополнительные проверки *самого кода*. Разбирать *сам код* на Python разумно парсером Python, а не создавать и поддерживать его кусочек по новой.
  - И если уж заставлять этим заниматься парсер Python, можно интегрировать синтаксис плотнее в язык, например указывать тип аргумента **непосредственно** рядом с ним. Что уже сделано аннотациями в [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), но [аннотации постепенно становятся только type hint'ами и больше ничем](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#non-typing-usage-of-annotations).