# Прошу помощи в объяснении логики аннотаций типов (type hints)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Коллеги, прошу помощи в аннотировании типов. Я либо не понимаю логики, либо у меня что-то не так настроено в PyCharm либо я просто что-то не так делаю. Буду благодарен за любые разъяснения. Документацию по type hints я читал.

Мне бы хотелось (так я понимаю логику), чтобы если я аннотировал некий тип переменной, то если я пытаюсь в эту переменную положить что-то другое, мне бы среда (в моем случае - PyCharm) подсказала, что я что-то делаю не так.

Но, по факту, в некоторых случаях, при явных несоответствиях типов, никаких предупреждений не выдается.

Пример 1.

```
d: dict[int, list[int]] = {1: [4], 2: ['d'], 3: ['g']}
```

Некоторыми значениями словаря является `list[str]` при аннотированном `list[int]`. Предупреждения нет.

Однако, если ВСЕ значения буду ошибочными - предупреждение будет:

```
d: dict[int, list[int]] = {1: ['4'], 2: ['d'], 3: ['g']}
```

Пример 2. Тоже, но со списками.

```
a: list[list[int]] = [[1], 2, 3]
```

Не вызывает предупреждение.

А вот так, вызовет:

```
a: list[list[int]] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Возможно, такие типы надо не так аннотировать?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-46009/False-negative-for-List-and-incompatible-type

Comment: @andreymal Прочитал, спасибо! Вот [нашел еще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788593/Почему-интерпретатор-питона-не-проверяет-type-hints?rq=1) у нас:. То есть если коротко - не проверяем или проверяем, но не все. И вообще, мы за пользователя думать не обязаны. Так?

Comment: Не путайте интерпретатор и IDE. В IDE есть баг, а интерпретатор вообще полностью игнорирует аннотации

Comment: @andreymal разговор об IDE. Так это все таки баг или политика разработчиков PyCharm и делать с этим они ничего не собираются? `In general, we always assume that user knows better and restrain from putting extra warnings in the editor. `

Comment: Не в курсе про политику, но в крайнем случае всегда можно использовать mypy, который будет ругаться на все приведённые в вопросе примеры

Comment: @andreymal я правильно понял, что mypy это отдельно запускаемый модуль? Или его можно каким-то образом "подключить" к PyCharm?